# How do I fix the width and height of my latex math term?

Tags: html, css, mathjax

***How do I fix the width and height of my latex math term?***

I am currently coding an interactive web function where I can click on the latex math term and it'll cancel to zero. However, right now, it is a bit jumpy/glitchy because the size of the first math term changes (highlighted in orange as shown in the picture) once the user clicks on it.

[image: Original State]

[image: After User Clicks on First Term]

Is there a way where I can set the width and height of the orange box to constant width before and after clicking?

```
<p>
<span class="special">Mass Continuity Equation:</span> 
<span class="first" id="first" data-click-state="1">\({{\partial \rho} \over {\partial t}}\)</span>
<span id="second">\(+\)</span> 
<span id="third" data-click-state="1">\({{\partial u} \over {\partial x}}\)</span> 
<span id="symbol"> \(+\) </span> 
<span id="fourth" data-click-state="1"> \({{\partial v} \over {\partial y}}\)</span> 
<span id="fifth">\(+\)</span> 
<span id="sixth" data-click-state="1"> \({{\partial w} \over {\partial z}}\) </span>
<span id="seventh">\(= 0\)</span> 
</p>
```

After user clicks the first term, this will be rendered:

```
<p>
<span class="special">Mass Continuity Equation:</span> 
<span class="first" id="first" data-click-state="0">\(\require{cancel}\cancelto{0} {{\partial \rho} \over {\partial t}}\)</span>
<span id="second">\(+\)</span> 
<span id="third" data-click-state="1">\({{\partial u} \over {\partial x}}\)</span> 
<span id="symbol"> \(+\) </span> 
<span id="fourth" data-click-state="1"> \({{\partial v} \over {\partial y}}\)</span> 
<span id="fifth">\(+\)</span> 
<span id="sixth" data-click-state="1"> \({{\partial w} \over {\partial z}}\) </span>
<span id="seventh">\(= 0\)</span> 
</p>
```

CSS code:

```
p { font-size: 30px;}
```

Codepen:

[CODEPEN LINK](http://codepen.io/harisdanial97/pen/xxEdWaW)

Comment: The size of the box wil stay the same if your `0` is positioned `absolute` or is `float`ing. Would you mind providing a working `codepen` or `snippet`?

Comment: Here is my codepen link: https://codepen.io/harisdanial97/pen/xxEdWaW

I'm not quite sure what you meant by positioning my 0 as absolute or float??


@DavidYKHan

Comment: I am sorry. I have no knowledge on latex math. Your `span` size changes as you click it. Try wraping those `span`s with `div`s styled with `display: inline-flex;`. Giving margins/paddings around your `span`s will fix your problem.

Comment: If I add margins/paddings, the newly generated term will have these paddings and margins as well. It does not make the old and new terms have the same size of the "orange box".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\phantom{}` to make a space that is the size of the canceled expression and use `\llap{}` to place the uncanceled expression on top of it, as in

```latex
\require{cancel}
\phantom{\cancelto{0}{\partial\rho \over \partial t}}
\llap{{\partial\rho \over \partial t}\kern .7em}
```

(The `\kern .7em` is to get the derivative placed properly within the space of the canceled term, and was determined experimentally.)

Note that you can use the `action` extension to handle toggling between the uncanceled sand canceled versions, so you really don't need javascript to accomplish this particular example.

Here is an example that uses `\toggle` actions to flip between uncanceled and canceled versions:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML"></script>

$$
\require{cancel}\require{action}
\def\dd#1#2{{\partial#1 \over \partial#2}}
\def\Cdd#1#2{\cancelto{0}{\dd{#1}{#2}}}
\def\Tdd#1#2{
  \toggle
    {\phantom{\Cdd{#1}{#2}}\llap{\dd{#1}{#2}\kern.6em}}
    {\color{red}{\Cdd{#1}{#2}}}
  \endtoggle
}
\Tdd \rho t + \; \Tdd u x + \; \Tdd v y + \; \Tdd w z
$$
```